# Estimation of Default Probability using Merton's model

Tags: credit-risk, default-probability, merton-model

There is an explanation of `Risk Neutral Default Probability` using a Firm's Equity price here - https://www.mathworks.com/help/risk/default-probability-using-the-merton-model-for-structural-credit-risk.html.

However, there is an equation which states that

$\sigma_E = \frac{A}{E} N \left(d_1\right) \sigma_A$

How is this formula derived?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you see in the third equation on that Mathworks page, the Merton model postulates that the value of equity equals the value on a residual claim on a company's assets after the creditor has been repaid. Economically speaking, equity is a call option on the asset value $A$ with strike price equal to the liability $L$, the formula for which is

$$
E=AN(d_1)-Le^{-rT}N(d_2)
$$

We further note that the variance of the asset process is (with a bit of *handwaverianism*)

$$\sigma^2\left(\frac{dA_t}{A_t}\right)\equiv \sigma_a^2dt$$

Finally, we know for a call option that $ \frac{\partial E}{\partial A}=N(d_1)$ which is also colloquially called *Delta*. Thus

\begin{align}
E&=AN(d_1)-Le^{-rT}N(d_2) \\
\Rightarrow dE&=N(d_1)dA\\
\Rightarrow \frac{dE}{E}&=\frac{1}{E}N(d_1)dA\\
\Rightarrow \frac{dE}{E}&=\frac{A}{E}N(d_1)\frac{dA}{A}
\end{align}

and ultimately

$$
\sigma_E\equiv \sigma\left(\frac{dE}{E}\right)=\frac{A}{E}N(d_1)\sigma\left(\frac{dA}{A}\right)=\frac{A}{E}N(d_1)\sigma_A
$$